# Flagging bugbears

Tags: discussion, flagging

Yesterday, I flagged a post because it was off-topic. The flag was declined by Zizouz212 on the basis that the help center says it's on-topic. The help center says no such thing.

Then when I flagged it again to communicate this to him, he declined that too on the basis that flags "shouldn't be used for communication"? Of course flags are for communication, to communicate things to the mods so they can do something about them.

Can someone set this moderator straight on his job description?

Comment: Please give us a link to the post you flagged.

Comment: Zizouz212 (and the other mods) can often be found in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25118/the-bikeshed)

Comment: Zizouz212 likely meant that flags shouldn't be used for *conversation*, which is exactly correct. You had already communicated the perceived problem and the moderator had already responded; raising another flag to respond to that response is not appropriate. Better to ask for clarification on meta, as you have done here, after the first flag is declined.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The help-center very well says that hardware is on-topic:

> This site is not limited to software, but also covers art, literature,
>   **hardware**, databases and more.

https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (end of first paragraph, bolded by me)

You just missed this part, probably only looking into the bullet point list. That can happen and the flag was declined based on that misunderstanding. The following flags then based on that it all started with a simple misunderstanding.

So there is no need to set the moderator straight, it was all right. We are in any case still thankful to your commitment and hoping for more input in the future, in that case the flag might not been have been helpful, but in the next case it might well be. So please don't be disappointed from this encounter.